# Samba Domain Member and DNS Problems

Tags: dns, active-directory, fedora, samba

I am trying to use my Fedora 34 workstation as a domain member but I'm having problems.  First problem is that when I join the domain, I get an dns error.

**net ads join -U Administrator**

```
Enter Administrator's password:
Using short domain name -- HOME
Joined 'FSDM01' to dns domain 'home.test-server.lan'
DNS Update for fsdm01.home.test-server.lan failed: ERROR_DNS_UPDATE_FAILED
DNS update failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

I have created similar domain members in Debian and both of them work just fine.  The DC is also Debian.

```
DC01 (10.0.0.19) = Debian Domain Controller
DM01 (10.0.0.14) = Debian Domain Member
DM02 (10.0.0.16) = Debian Domain Member
FSDM01 (10.0.0.17) = Fedora Domain Member
realm = home.test-server.lan
```

I can ping hostname from and between all Debian hosts.  I can ping all Debian hostnames from Fedora.  I cannot ping Fedora hostname from any of the Debian hosts.

Comment: You're likely to get better help for this on [the sister-site] https://superuser.com or even https://serverfault.com/, as this is more of a sysadmin question than a programming one.

Comment: Thanks.  Will do.  Is there a problem with posting to both?

Comment: serverFault would be my go-to (not many DCs used outside enterprise/lab/geek-out networks, AFAIK). superuser.com may just redirect you to serverfault anyhow, but maybe not ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Needed to setup a proper DNS configuration for the DC.

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Changing_the_DNS_Back_End_of_a_Samba_AD_DC